# If $a_n$ positive and bounded, $(a_n + n^{-1})^ra_n \to a$ implies $(a_n)^ra_n \to a$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of non-negative numbers such that $|a_n| \leq C$.
Suppose that $(a_n + n^{-1})^ra_n \to a$ for some $a$, where $r \geq 0$ and real.

How to show that 
$$(a_n)^ra_n \to a$$? That is the $n^{-1}$ can be neglected? This should be simple but I can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you multiply out $(a_n+n^{-1})^r$ you obtain an expression (a sum of terms) at which the term with the highest power of $a_n$ is $(a_n)^r$, if $r\ge 1$. If $0\le r<1$ then $(a_n)^r<a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

By the mean value theorem$$
\Bigl(a_n+\frac1n\Bigr)^ra_n-(a_n)^ra_n=a_n\Bigl(\Bigl(a_n+\frac1n\Bigr)^r-(a_n)^r\Bigr)=a_n\,\frac1n\,(r\,z_n^{r-1}),\quad a_n<z_n<a_n+\frac1n.
$$